# On the first Local Cohomology module of a complete local ring of depth $1$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-cohomology, primary-decomposition

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be $\mathfrak m$-adically complete Noetherian local ring of depth $1$. Thus the local cohomology module $H^1_{\mathfrak m}(R)$ is a non-zero Artinian module.

My question is:

> How to show that the module
> $H^1_{\mathfrak m}(R)$ is a finitely generated $R$-module if and only if the set $ \{P\in \mathrm{Ass}(R): \dim (R/P)=1\}$ is empty ?

I can show this if $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay, by using Grothendieck local duality, but otherwise, I have no idea in general.

Please help.

Comment: How do you prove it when $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay?

Comment: @Youngsu: well first of all if $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay of depth $1$ then the local-Cohomology module in question never is Noetherian... I was talking about a module $M$ over a Cohen-Macaulay ring of any dimension $d$ in general ... in that case, to show the first local Cohomology module of $M$ is Noetherian , one uses Matlis dual to pass to $Ext^{d-1}(M, \omega)$ and then localizes at non-maximal prime ideals to determine when it is supported at just the unique maximal ideal ...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Did you try to use the Cohen-structure theorem?

Comment: Can you provide a reference or motivation for this question?

Comment: @Youngsu: I've not really thought about applying Cohen structure theorem here as I'm not sure how to ...   could you please help ?

Comment: I haven't worked out it or have an answer to your question. But following your scheme for the Cohen-Macaulay case, here is what one can try. Present $S = A/I$, where $A$ is a complete regular local ring (which of course is Cohen-Macaulay) and apply your argument where $R$ is replaced by $A$ and $M$ is replaced by $R$.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the main question, but it does give a related condition on when local cohomology is finitely generated.

Consider the following result:

> **Lemma**. If $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is a local ring, then an artinian $R$-module $N$ is finitely generated if and only if $\text{Att}(N)\subseteq\{\mathfrak{m}\}$.

We can combine this with the non-vanishing result of Macdonald and Sharp:

> **Theorem** Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be local and $M$ a $d$-dimensional non-zero finitely generated $R$-module. Then $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{d}(M)\neq 0$ and
>   $$\text{Att}(H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{d}(M))=\{ \mathfrak{p}\in\text{Ass}(M):\text{dim}\,R/\mathfrak{p}=d\}.$$

You can see that if $R$ is a (not necessarily complete) equidimensional local ring of dimension $d$, that the claim in the original question holds since $\{ \mathfrak{p}\in\text{Ass}(R):\text{dim}\,R/\mathfrak{p}=d\}$ will be all the minimal primes.

Information on attached primes can be found in Matsumura or in Brodmann and Sharp's book on Local Cohomology.

Do you have a reason to impose a depth, rather than dimension, condition on your ring, and do you actually know if the statement in the original question is true? I am not able to find a reference for it.